# Ember js - toggle current and previous value passed to an action

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following simple pattern to toggle the visibility of three different divs when three buttons are clicked:

**templates/index.hbs**

```html
<button {{action 'toggleBox' 'boxOne'}}>One</button>
<button {{action 'toggleBox' 'boxTwo'}}>Two</button>
<button {{action 'toggleBox' 'boxThree'}}>Three</button>
{{#if boxOne}}
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
{{/if}} 
{{#if boxTwo}}
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
{{/if}} 
{{#if boxThree}}
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
{{/if}}
```

**controllers/index.js**

```js
toggleBox: function(boxName) {
  this.toggleProperty(boxName);
},
```

The problem is that I need only 1 box to show at a time- if **boxOne** is visible, then clicking **boxTwo** should show **boxTwo** and hide **boxOne**.

I have tried to save the property name in a variable after the value is toggled, so that it can be set to false when a different box is opened, but I can't get the right pattern.

```js
toggleBox: function(boxName) {
  /***Here I would like to set the previous value of boxName to false***/
  this.toggleProperty(boxName);
  //put the current value of boxName in a variable to use in the next run of the action.
  this.set('currentBox', boxName);
  var current = this.get('currentBox');
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this way of handling the `currentBox` attribute is a bit less hackish.

```
currentBox: '',

toggleBox: function(boxName) {
  this.set('currentBox', boxName);
},
boxOneIsActive: function() {
  return this.get('currentBox') === 'boxOne');
}.property('currentBox')
/* ... */
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't set the value of boxName to true, and so nothing appears when the action is fired.

Comment: `currentBox` is used to know which box is active. The booleans you will be using in your templates would be computed attributes based on that one. In my example, you would do `{{#if boxOneIsActive}} ... {{/if}}`

Comment: in my reponse, maybe the name `toggleBox(boxName)` is misleading, would rather be `activateBox(boxName)`

Comment: I've managed to get this working- thanks. I didn't realise at first that the code for the computed property (boxOneIsActive) would need to be repeated for every box on the page. 
I like that the code in my solution doesn't require that. Would your solution be better with performance?

Comment: I don't know about performance but I feel like it's a bit less hackish and more straightforward. I like to define explicitely the attributes in my ember objects in order to keep everything obvious. "toggling" attributes implicitely like you do can lead to maintenability issues I think.

Comment: Good point- I think that your more explicit method is better if you don't have a big number of boxes to toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```js
toggleBox: function(boxName) {
  var current = this.get('currentBox');
  if ((current) && (current !== boxName)) {
    this.set(current, false);
  };
  this.toggleProperty(boxName);
  this.set('currentBox', boxName);
},
```

The above creates a property 'currentBox' which is available when the action next runs. It's important to have **this.toggleProperty(current);** in an if statement to avoid an error when the action runs the first time.